# MySQL Workbench Import Data Wizard Not Importing All Records

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to MySQL, and Databases in general. I have installed and am using MySQL Workbench 6.3. I am attempting to import data from a CVS file with several tens of thousands of rows (records). When I use the import data wizard from Workbench, the process seems to work. . . except only a small subset of records will import. No error is thrown. What is the problem? How can I import all of my data.

-EDIT-

The data I'm attempting to use is financial data provided by Lending Club. The raw CVS files are downloadable here: https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action

Here is the first three rows copied and pasted from Note Pad:

**DATA EXAMPLE:**

```
id,member_id,loan_amnt,funded_amnt,funded_amnt_inv,term,int_rate,installment,grade,sub_grade,emp_title,emp_length,home_ownership,annual_inc,verification_status,issue_d,loan_status,pymnt_plan,url,desc,purpose,title,zip_code,addr_state,dti,delinq_2yrs,earliest_cr_line,inq_last_6mths,mths_since_last_delinq,mths_since_last_record,open_acc,pub_rec,revol_bal,revol_util,total_acc,initial_list_status,out_prncp,out_prncp_inv,total_pymnt,total_pymnt_inv,total_rec_prncp,total_rec_int,total_rec_late_fee,recoveries,collection_recovery_fee,last_pymnt_d,last_pymnt_amnt,next_pymnt_d,last_credit_pull_d,collections_12_mths_ex_med,mths_since_last_major_derog,policy_code

1077501,1296599,5000,5000,4975, 36 months,10.65%,162.87,B,B2,,10+ years,RENT,24000,VERIFIED - income,Dec-11,Fully Paid,n,https://www.lendingclub.com/browse/loanDetail.action?loan_id=1077501, Borrower added on 12/22/11 > I need to upgrade my business technologies.<br>,credit_card,Computer,860xx,AZ,27.65,0,Jan-85,1,,,3,0,13648,83.70%,9,f,0,0,5861.071414,5831.78,5000,861.07,0,0,0,Jan-15,171.62,,Jan-15,0,,1

1077430,1314167,2500,2500,2500, 60 months,15.27%,59.83,C,C4,Ryder,< 1 year,RENT,30000,VERIFIED - income source,Dec-11,Charged Off,n,https://www.lendingclub.com/browse/loanDetail.action?loan_id=1077430, Borrower added on 12/22/11 > I plan to use this money to finance the motorcycle i am looking at. I plan to have it paid off as soon as possible/when i sell my old bike. I only need this money because the deal im looking at is to good to pass up.<br><br>  Borrower added on 12/22/11 > I plan to use this money to finance the motorcycle i am looking at. I plan to have it paid off as soon as possible/when i sell my old bike.I only need this money because the deal im looking at is to good to pass up. I have finished college with an associates degree in business and its takingmeplaces<br>,car,bike,309xx,GA,1,0,Apr-99,5,,,3,0,1687,9.40%,4,f,0,0,1008.71,1008.71,456.46,435.17,0,117.08,1.11,Apr-13,119.66,,Sep-13,0,,1
```

Comment: show the table structure. show that data (just a small fraction of it)

Comment: There must be something special with the not-imported records. Maybe an invalid format? Check also for index violations (duplicate keys).

Comment: The "2013 - 2014" declined loan data imported fine for me (after removing the first line that was a note, not removing it caused problems). Maybe you can provide details, such as the import steps you take, and errors you encounter, and the tables it created. I see 138000 rows.